# access to local request fails using local telegram bot api

Tags: localhost, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have been trying to deploy the local telegram api. I logOut the bot from the official website. When I start the local api, my access to 127.0.0.1:10802/botToken/getMe keeps failing. 10802 is the port I set. how should i do? What could go wrong

#start the local api
/telegram-bot-api.exe --api-id=myid --api-hash=mytoken --local --log="D:/TG/test.log" --temp-dir="D:/TG/temp" --dir="D:/TG/work" --http-port=10802 -v 3

I want to use local API to control Bot to send large file translations to groups
i am going to use package PTB20.5

Comment: For reference: There has already been some discussion of this problem on Telegram: https://t.me/pythontelegrambottalk/243047